# A good example using cookies with Google Oauth 2 in php?

Tags: php, cookies, oauth-2.0, session-cookies, google-oauth

I'm trying to make a little Php website where users can simply connect through their Google account.
That's why I'm using Oauth 2.0, with no problem getting connected to my account (I followed the official [Google Oauth2 tutorial](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app)).

The next step is "remember" the users (with cookies), so people will not have to connect through google each time they go onto the site.

I'm searching for a "good" way to use cookies with Oauth2. I'm afraid of security breaches or things like that, and would like to learn the best ways.

My problem is that, depsite some researches, I could not find a clear website showing a (recent, not 10 yo...) example of Google Oauth2 + Php + Cookies management example.

Do you know some example, solution or best practice ?
How can I do ?

Comment: SImply store hashed and salted microtime() string along with other user fields in database, and store that hashed value in cookie. If the value in cookie matches some user record, log the user in.If you concencate two hashed strings together, there is really small chance of your app being unsafe, at least on your end. User being tricked into giving away his cookie, that is whole different story, but that is most of the time not your concern. Do security well on your end, but let the protection of the user to himself

Comment: Thanks :)
I'll do it this way